# Can't find license key anywhere in Here api

Tags: android, here-api

I am not able to find the license key from here maps. I have my app ID and app Code already but not the license key.
I have a plan of Public Starter.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your license key from [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/android/) .

Click On **Get A Key** and register your project . From there you'll get your link

Comment: @KartikShah as per [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/topics/credentials.html) document you just need to add App_id and App_Code

Comment: But when i used evaluation plan which is for 90 days free trial ,i got license key and now i have purchased a  Public Starter plan there is no license key there and i have to used this license key in my manifest 
If i am not using license key ,my application crashes .

Comment: @KartikShah Please Go through [this steps](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/README.md) .

Comment: thats the only problem i am facing .when i go trhough my project detail page and opening the plan .No where i can find license key ,only App-id and App code is there .

Comment: @KartikShah  post screenshot of your account . Remove Your credentials at the time of attaching

Comment: Please Keep In mind  that in [this link](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/README.md) . license key is for premium version Sdk as shown in images

Comment: How can i select premium version SDK ?